# interprocess communication with and without .net

Tags: .net, ipc

I'm developing a .net WPF application, and I would like to put in a two way IPC mechanism. I realize named pipes and remoting are options, however I would like to make the mechanism not dependent on .NET for non-.NET applications to communicate with my application.

What does SO recommend as a solution to this? WM_COPYDATA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use named pipes, in this case.

Named pipes are [fully supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365780(VS.85).aspx) in native code as well as .NET.  They provide a very fast, efficient way of working, and are very easy to work with in .NET for your current development.  This is a much better option (in just about every way, IMO) to WM_COPYDATA.

That being said, there are quite a few [Interprocess Communication options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx).  Many of these work both in .NET and native code, including:

- Clipboard
- COM
- File Mapping
- Pipes
- Windows Sockets

Comment: Agreed that they beat WM_COPYDATA.  Not sure that they're as well-supported as TCP/IP solutions, though.  (I'm including things like WCF here, not just plain HTTP.)

Comment: @Steven: That's why I included Windows Sockets (last option), which includes TCP/IP (as well as UDP sockets).

Comment: @Steven: Pipes are very well supported on Windows, though - so anywhere WM_COPYDATA would work, pipes should work.

Comment: While anything capable of SDK calls can do pipe I/O, .NET only got decent support in 3.5.  Even then, it's just a thin wrapper over the OS and what it's wrapping isn't a whole lot of fun.  I've used named pipes extensively for IPC and RPC, over the last 15 years, and I still don't like them.  In the end, the IPC part is implemented over shared memory, just like TCP/IP to localhost, but you get all the complexity of Windows file security and lose access to SOAP, REST and all the rest.  It's not a stupid choice by any means, but it wouldn't be where I turn to first.  My $0.02.

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes wouldn't be .NET specific.  Neither would shared memory mapping or even TCP/IP.  As for .NET remoting, I'd avoid it, even for cases where both sides are .NET.